# Sort an array of strings that contain a dates in C# or order by in angularJS?

Tags: c#, html, angularjs

I have an array of dates from this form:

```
string[] arr=["08.02.2017","09.02.2017","30.01.2017","31.01.2017"]
```

what is the best way to sort this kind of array in c#? I want that the order will of the array will be in descending order. I need to show this data inside an select element, maybe i can order this somehow with angularJS?

Comment: In c# or angularjs ?

Comment: Don`t mind, both will be a good solution for me

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in C#:

```
arr = arr.OrderByDescending(s => DateTime.Parse(s, new CultureInfo("de-DE"))).ToArray();
```

Another way with `ParseExact`:

```
arr = arr.OrderByDescending(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd.MM.yyyy", null)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Trying_To_Know: i have used de-DE because we use `.` as date-separator. You might also use your own.